# result.batch.entityResults gives undefines error

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm making a nodejs app running on google app engine cloud datastore. The gcloud module is installed but when I type result.batch.entityResults it gives me an undefined error after query it gives an undefined error.

```
function signup(minHeight,maxHeight,callback) {

  var heightRangeQuery = {
    kinds: [{ name: 'Person' }],
    filter: {
      // Combine multiple filters by using a compositeFilter.
      compositeFilter: {
        operator: 'AND',
        filters: [{
          propertyFilter: {
            property: { name: 'height' },
            operator: 'GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL',
            value: { integerValue: minHeight }
          }
        }, {
          propertyFilter: {
            property: { name: 'height' },
            operator: 'LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL',
            value: { integerValue: maxHeight }
          }
        }]
      },
    }
  };

  datastore.runQuery({
    query: heightRangeQuery
  }).execute(function(err, result) {
    // Iterate over the results.
    if (!err && result.batch.entityResults) {
      result.batch.entityResults.forEach(function(er) {
        var entity = er.entity;
        console.log(entity.properties.firstName.stringValue, ' ',
            entity.properties.lastName.stringValue, ', ',
            entity.properties.height.integerValue, ' inches tall');
      });
      if (result.batch.moreResults == 'NOT_FINISHED') {
        var endCursor = result.batch.endCursor;
        heightRangeQuery.startCursor = endCursor;
        // Reissue the query to get more results...
      }
    }
    callback(err);
  });
}
```

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. The tag batch-file is not appropritate for this question. I suggest looking at the [info tab](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/info) when you click on the tag so you know what you should and shouldn't use it for.

Comment: Is `result.batch` defined in the response?

Comment: no it is not defines anywhere i thought it is in the gcloud module. is it ?